# Any state of polarization produced from two different states of polarization?

Tags: electromagnetism, polarization

My textbook on Electromagnetic Waves says that two orthogonal states of polarization can be combined to produce any arbitrary state of polarization.
Is the same true if the two distinct constituent states are not orthogonal?

I personally think this is true assuming a model similar to vector basis is followed.

Comment: Yes, you can chose a basis for Jones vectors that is not an orthogonal basis.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, you can use positive and negative coefficients; in light combining, you can only use positive coefficients.   So, you need orthogonal 
polarized sources.

Practically, a single polarizer and a few quarter-wave plates will yield any random, plane or circular or elliptical polarizations you might want.

Comment: You would need a quarter wave plate and a half wave plate. Just quarter wave plates wouldn't move you around the Poincaré sphere.

Comment: A half wave plate is twice a quarter wave plate, was my thinking.  Same  material, twice the thickness, so two quarter wave plates is a substitute.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - i realised I misspoke lightly. Two quarter wave plates are able to replicate a half wave plate when their axes are aligned, but with just a half wave plate you cannot replicate the effects of a quarter wave plate. To traverse the Poincaré sphere, you have to be able to change transform between linear and circular polarisation.